# Enviar dados para um ficheiro pdf e email

Tags: css, html5

Boa tarde gostaria de guardar dados de um formulário de uma página html quando os users fazem o registo e submissão num ficheiro pdf e ser enviado para um email predefinido mas não sei como fazer isso, tenho o formulário criado da seguinte forma:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formulário</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2> Preencha o formulário abaixo para participar no curso de Linux Administração</h2><br/>

<form action="Script_do_Formulario.php" method="post">

<!-- DADOS PESSOAIS-->
<fieldset>
 <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
 <table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="email">
   </td>
   <td>
    <label for="sobrenome">Apelido: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label>Data de Nascimento: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="4" maxlength="2" value="dd"> 
   <input type="text" name="mes" size="6" maxlength="2" value="mm"> 
   <input type="text" name="ano" size="8" maxlength="4" value="aaaa">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="rg">Localidade: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="rg" size="13" maxlength="13"> 
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label>Código Postal:</label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="cpf" size="9" maxlength="9"> - <input type="text" name="cpf2" size="2" maxlength="2">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>

<br />
<!-- ENDEREÇO -->
<fieldset>
 <legend>Morada</legend>
 <table cellspacing="10">

  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="rua">Rua:</label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="rua">
   </td>
   <td>
    <label for="numero">Numero:</label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="numero" size="4">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="bairro">Localidade: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="bairro">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="estado">Distrito:</label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <select name="estado"> 
    <option value="av">Aveiro</option> 
    <option value="be">Beja</option> 
    <option value="br">Braga</option> 
    <option value="bg">Bragança</option> 
    <option value="cb">Castelo Branco</option> 
    <option value="cm">Coimbra</option> 
    <option value="ev">Évora</option> 
    <option value="fr">Faro</option> 
    <option value="gd">Guarda</option> 
    <option value="lr">Leiria</option> 
    <option value="lx">Lisboa</option> 
    <option value="Pg">Portalegre</option> 
    <option value="pt">Porto</option> 
    <option value="st">Santarém</option> 
    <option value="sb">Setúbal</option> 
    <option value="vc">Viana do Castelo</option> 
    <option value="vr">Vila Real</option> 
    <option value="vs">Viseu</option> 
    <option value="im">Ilha da Madeira</option> 
    <option value="ia">Ilha dos Açores</option> 
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="cidade">Cidade: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="cidade">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="cep">Código Postal: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="cp" size="3" maxlength="4"> - <input type="text" name="cp2" size="2" maxlength="3">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>
<br />

<!-- DADOS DE LOGIN -->
<fieldset>
 <legend>Contacto Email</legend>
 <table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="email">E-mail: </label>
   </td>
   <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="email">
   </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Limpar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas utilizando HTML você não conseguirá fazê-lo de forma **fácil** (há bibliotecas em JavaScript que poderiam cuidar desta paete) mas algo **simples** de implementar, mas requerendo um cliente de e-mail instalado e configurado no computador do usuário, é simplesmente fazer:

```
<form action="mailto:«conta de e-mail»" method="get">
   ...
</form>
```

Daí os dados do formulário serão enviados para o endereço de e-mail indicado no formulário.

Mas também vi que teu formulário, a princípio, enviaria os dados para um programa em PHP, o "Script_do_Formulario.php", neste caso sua dúvida seria também nesta linguagem?

Então um programa bem simples para receber e enviar os dados do formulário para um endereço específico de e-mail seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    /* lê os campos via POST */
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    ...

    /* alguma validação */
    ...

    /* monta a mensagem */
    $mensagem = "Ficha de Inscrição\n".
        "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n".
        "Nome : ".$nome."\n".
        "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n";

    mail('usuario@email.com','Ficha de Inscrição', $mensagem);
?>
```

Claro, este programa recupera apenas "nome" do formulário (é possível perceber a lógica para fazer o mesmo com os demais campos) e monta o corpo de uma mensagem para ser enviada pela função mail() do próprio PHP.

Comment: Sim, pois nunca programei em PHP

Comment: Acrescente a tag 'php' na tua pergunta.

Comment: em que sitio em concreto ponho a tag 'php' no meu código? pergunto porque não estou a entender em que sitio